# Почему если из jsp убрать бин, выводит просто наименования, а иначе происходит ClassCastException?

Tags: java, jsp, classcastexception

Пытаюсь написать простое `crud`-приложение.
Вводные:

### SmokingAccessories - abstract class:

```
public class Cigarettes extends SmokingAccessories {

    private final String additives;

    private final String strength;


    public Cigarettes(Integer id, String name, int price, String description, LocalDate dateOfIssue,
                      int shelfLifeYear, String additives, String strength) {
        super(id, name, price, description, dateOfIssue, shelfLifeYear);
        this.additives = additives;
        this.strength = strength;
    }

    public Cigarettes(String name, int price, String description, LocalDate dateOfIssue,
                      int shelfLifeYear, String additives, String strength) {
        super(null, name, price, description, dateOfIssue, shelfLifeYear);
        this.additives = additives;
        this.strength = strength;
    }

    public String getAdditives() {
        return additives;
    }

    public String getStrength() {
        return strength;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Cigarettes{" +
                super.toString() +
                "additives='" + additives + '\'' +
                ", strength='" + strength + '\'' +
                "} " + "\n";
    }
}

    public class CigarettesServlet extends HttpServlet {
    List<Cigarettes> cigarettes = Arrays.asList(
            new Cigarettes("Parlament", 239, "Ультратонкие сигареты с насыщенным вкусом и приятным ароматом",
                    LocalDate.of(2022, Month.MAY, 15), 2, "Ментол", "Легкие"),
            new Cigarettes("Winston", 185, "Крепкие сигареты из лучших сортов табака Гватемалы",
                    LocalDate.of(2023, Month.JANUARY, 31), 2,
                    "Без дополнительных добавок", "Крепкие"),
            new Cigarettes("Русский стиль", 200, "Средней крепости сигареты для мидлов",
                    LocalDate.of(2020, Month.FEBRUARY, 12), 2,
                    "С добавлением табака", "Средние")
    );


  

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        req.setAttribute("lOfCigarettes", cigarettes);
        req.getRequestDispatcher("cigarettes.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }
```

### И `jsp`:

```html
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java"%>
<%@ page import="org.example.model.Cigarettes" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cigarettes</title>
    <style>
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: 2px solid #000;
        }

        td, th {
            vertical-align: top;
            padding: 5px;
            border: 2px solid #000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h3><a href="index.jsp">Home</a></h3>
<hr/>
<h2>Cigarettes</h2>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>DateOfIssue</th>
        <th>ShelfLifeYear</th>
        <th>Additives</th>
        <th>Strength</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${lOfCigarettes}" var="ciga">
        <jsp:useBean id="ciga" type="org.example.model.Cigarettes"/>

        <td>${ciga.id}</td>
        <td>${ciga.name}</td>
        <td>${ciga.price}</td>
        <td>${ciga.description}</td>
        <td>${ciga.dateOfIssue}</td>
        <td>${ciga.shelfLifeYear}</td>
        <td>${ciga.additives}</td>
        <td>${ciga.strength}</td>

    </c:forEach>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

При выводе, если из `jsp` убрать бин, выводит просто наименования "ciga.id".

Если с бином то ошибка в нем:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.example.model.Cigarettes
> (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap';
> org.example.model.Cigarettes is in unnamed module of loader
> org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @a299aee)

Объясните пожалуйста где ошибся или как правильно кастить?

Comment: Из вопроса не знаю, какая версия jsp используется и какие другие библиотеки присутствуют, это может влиять как выводить данные. Можете попробовать выводить данные по другому, вместо `<td>${ciga.id}</td>` писать `<td><c:out value="${ciga.id}"/></td>`  [Пример взял отсюда](https://javadeveloperzone.com/java-web-basic/jstl-foreach-loop/)

Comment: Похоже что цикл тоже не работает? Есть дескриптор приложения? Какой сервер используется?

Comment: @RomanC https://github.com/VladimirJG/smoke_house/blob/master/pom.xml (при правке основного вопроса не дает вставить, поэтому ссылка на помник, если не трудно гляньте пожалуйста, цикл действительно не работает. Ошибка именно на бин org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Произошла ошибка при обработке [/cigarettes.jsp] в строке [39]
39:         <jsp:useBean id="ciga" type="org.example.model.Cigarettes"/>
)
Сервер - томкат.9.0.75

Comment: MrFylypenko https://github.com/VladimirJG/smoke_house/blob/master/pom.xml 
по другому тоже не получается. 
Может ли ошибка возникать из за наследования?  Может быть убрать абстрактный класс и сделать каждый класс товаров независимым?

Comment: @yaVodyanoy В сервлете там стоит `req.setAttribute("lOfCigarettes", castToString(cigarettes));` а в вопросе `req.setAttribute("lOfCigarettes", cigarettes);`

Comment: @RomanC Это уже были вариации на тему. Без разницы кастить к String или просто подавать значения - не работает. Убирал класс родитель, добавлял Serialaizer, подавал только String на вход - не работает.

Comment: @yaVodyanoy "не работает" - это не является проблемой. Если неизвестна причина, то проблему определить невозможно. А без этого вопрос считается некорректным. На такой вопрос невозможно дать ответ.

Comment: @RomanC Согласен полностью. Искал именно причину. В любом случае спасибо за участие!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось намного проще, в web.xml отсутствовали ссылки на ресурсы для корректной работы сервлетов...

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    </web-app>
```